# ADD self link for item in Custom ResponseHandler

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following ResponseHandler  to override a Data Rest Response Handlers. Instead of returning all data, the handler returns only data for the owner (logged in user- currently hardcoded).

```
package com.osde.prepo.controller;

import com.osde.prepo.entity.Company;
import com.osde.prepo.repository.CompanyRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

/**
 * customer controller to override some Data Rest Response Handlers
 */
@RepositoryRestController
public class CompanyController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompanyController.class);
    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyController(CompanyRepository repo) {
        companyRepository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/companies")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllCompaniesForCurrentUser() {
        logger.info("custom implementation for get called!!");
        List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
        companies = companyRepository.findByOwnerId("google-oauth2|107634743108791790006");

        // convert to HATEOAS
        CollectionModel<Company> resources = CollectionModel.of(companies);
        resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(CompanyController.class)
                .getAllCompaniesForCurrentUser())
                .withSelfRel());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }

  }
```

I get the following response, when consuming the API:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "companies": [
            {
                "ownerId": "google-oauth2|107634743108791790006",
                "name": "Company 1",
                "city": "Ort 1",
                "country": "Germany",
                "profile": "We are 1 ...",
                "logoUrl": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/companies"
        }
    }
}
```

The original API has the following response (including self-links to the items) **How do I have to change my code to get this response (paging is not of interest so far!**)?

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "companies": [
            {
                "ownerId": "google-oauth2|107634743108791790006",
                "name": "Company 1",
                "city": "Ort 1",
                "country": "Germany",
                "profile": "We are 1 ...",
                "logoUrl": null,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1"
                    },
                    "company": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/companies"
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/search"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to achieve this.  I have assumed that your Entity has a getter for id as getId().It can be changed as per the code.

There is a need to extend this RepresentationModel on the entity class to get the add method.

eg

```
public class Company extends RepresentationModel<Company> implements Serializable {
```

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/companies")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllCompaniesForCurrentUser() {
        logger.info("custom implementation for get called!!");
        List<Company> companies = companyRepository.findByOwnerId("google-oauth2|107634743108791790006");
        for (Company company : companies) {
            Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(CompanyController.class)
                    .getCompaniesById(company.getId())).withSelfRel();
            company.add(selfLink);
        }
        Link link = linkTo(methodOn(CompanyController.class).getAllCompaniesForCurrentUser()).withSelfRel();
        CollectionModel<Company> result = CollectionModel.of(companies, link);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(companies);
    }
```

There is an another way to do this as well. This won't require any change on the Entity class.

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/companies")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllCompaniesForCurrentUser() {
        logger.info("custom implementation for get called!!");
        List<EntityModel<Company>> companies = companyRepository
                .findByOwnerId("google-oauth2|107634743108791790006")
                .stream()
                .map(this::generateLinks)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Company>> resource = CollectionModel.of(companies);
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(Company.class));
        resource.add(entityLinks.linksToSearchResources(Company.class));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(resource);    

    }

    private EntityModel<Company> generateLinks(Company company) {
        EntityModel<Company> resource = EntityModel.of(company);
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkToItemResource(Company.class, company.getId()).withSelfRel());
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(Company.class));
        resource.add(entityLinks.linksToSearchResources(Company.class));
        return resource;
    }
```

Comment: Is there still some thing remaining?

Comment: Yes - see my answer!

Comment: The updated code should solve your problem.

Comment: not quite - but we come closer. I do not have a controller-Method **getCompaniesById**
Do I have to create this method by overiding the standard API for that purpose - or is there an alternative way ?
And company does not have a method - **add()**

Comment: For getCompaniesById() consider replacing it with the suitable method that is present inside your controller class. ie the method whose link needs to be added.

Comment: I do not have an own method for that- because I use the API created by **Spring Boot Data Rest** 
So I have to create a method and override the "Standard Response Handler" -correct ?

Comment: check the updated answer the second way will help in that case.

Comment: Ok - that works - but I still have the following url for the collection:

`_links": {
        "companies": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }`
How do I get rid of  **{?page, size,sort}**
I commented out the lines with **linksToSearchResources()**, because I get the following error 
`Cannot resolve method 'linksToSearchResources' in 'EntityLinks'`

Comment: You must be using PagingAndSortingRepository try to use CrudRepository instead on the CompanyRepository in order to get rid of those params.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Ok- I will do so- temporarly. **Thanks for your time !**
At the end I would like to use paging and sorting. So allow one last question. 
**How do I implement this in my custom ResponseHandler?**

Comment: Didn't got your concern. Please elaborate further an example it will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

That points to the correct direction!
Now I get the following output:

```
[
    {
        "companyId": 1,
        "ownerId": "google-oauth2|107634743108791790006",
        "name": "Company 1",
        "city": "Ort 1",
        "country": "Germany",
        "profile": "We are 1 ...",
        "logoUrl": null,
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1"
            },
            {
                "rel": "companies",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies{?page,size,sort}"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to adjust the following aspects:

1. link to companies should be on the collection-level and just be http://localhost:8080/api/companies
2. rename links to _links